# Angular's $last for ngRepeat is always returning true

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jquery-isotope, web-frontend

I'm working on a project that uses AngularJS 1 and IsotopeJS for styling grid elements as they come in from an API call.  Because Isotope requires `$grid.isotope('reloadItems')` to be called after the items have been loaded into the DOM, I'm trying to use [$last](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat) to attach the call.

I made the following directive:

```
.directive("bookGrid", function(){
   return {
       scope: {
           mybooks: '='
       },
       restrict: "E",
       templateUrl: '/public/allBookGal.html'
   };
```

Where /allBookGal.html contains the following HTML code:

```
<div class="grid">
    <div class="grid-item" ng-repeat="mybook in mybooks" iso-helper>
        //Details about the loaded content
    </div>
</div>
```

I created the directive iso-helper to access the scope of ngRepeat and make the call when `scope.$last===true` as follows:

```
.directive("isoHelper", function(){
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        link: function(scope, elem, attr){

            console.log("This is pass : " + scope.$index + " . First? " + scope.$first + " . Middle? " + scope.$middle + " . Last? " + scope.$last);
            console.log(scope);

            if(scope.$last){
                //scope.grid.isotope('reloadItems');
            }

        }
    }
});
```

However, when this code executes, I receive the following result from the console:

```
This is pass : 0 . First? true . Middle? false . Last? true
This is pass : 1 . First? false . Middle? false . Last? true
This is pass : 2 . First? false . Middle? false . Last? true
This is pass : 3 . First? false . Middle? false . Last? true
This is pass : 4 . First? false . Middle? false . Last? true
This is pass : 5 . First? false . Middle? false . Last? true
```

Not only is this not the expected result, but when I expand the scope object after it was printed out during each pass, the values are what they should be.  i.e., the scope object printed after pass 0 has `$first==true` and `$last==false` and the scope object printed after 3 has `$middle==true` and `$last==false`.

Can anyone explain why the printed scope has the correct values, but the value's computed in link are wrong?

Edit: I passed in the array mybooks after trying it without isolating the scope.  I do not have any other ngRepeats within this page which could be affecting the binding of $last on the local scope.

Comment: Can you show an example of what your array/object looks like?

Comment: mybooks: [{title: "String", author: ["Me"], cover: "url", tags: ["Fiction"]}]